# Sharepoint designer is replacing french characters with &#65533;

Tags: character-encoding, sharepoint-designer

First of all, I'm not a web designer, I'm a programmer, so I'm working a bit out of my knowledge area.  However, as the person in my office who has some working knowledge of French, I'm stuck with this issue.

The Problem:
Sharepoint Designer is replacing all French accented characters with the &#65533; (square box or diamond-? �) character.

It doesn't appear to matter if I enter the 'é' character as alt-130 (in either design or source or as &eacute;

Everything works fine when editing, but when the file is saved and loaded into a browser, it replaces the characters.  When reloading into designer, the file shows the 65533 symbol.

EDIT: More info.

1. I use &#233; and save, close SP designer,
2. Reloading SP designer will show the é (instead of the code) in source.
3. Next reload will have replaced it with &#65533;

Question 1: (more important) HOW DO I STOP THIS!?
Question 2: (more interesting) Why does this happen?

Charset is iso-8859-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

fixed it and stopped sharepoint from modifying the source.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution works for me in certain environments, and does not work in other environments... Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this charset : 
windows-1252

Answer (score 0):

For me - the solution was to change the system locale: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7

**EDIT:**
Now I see that the link does not work anymore,
So briefly - the solution is to change the system locale.